# Laravel 5.7 - Pivot table attach()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, pivot-table

I cannot get `attach()` to work in my setup.

Each `User` can have many `Order`s which can have many `Product`s.

**User.php**

```php
    public function orders()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Order::class);
}
```

**Order.php**

```php
    public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

    public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class)
                ->withTimestamps()
                ->withPivot('qty');
}
```

**Product.php**

```php
    public function orders()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Order::class)
                ->withTimestamps()
                ->withPivot('qty');
}
```

I have a `create.blade.php` which is meant to show all available products and the quantity for each can be chosen, this is to be saved on the pivot table.

**create.blade.php**

```php
{{ Form::open(array('url' => '/orders/store')) }}

@foreach ($products as $product)
    <div>
        <span class="mealname">{{ $product->name }}</span>
        <hr>
        <p>{{ $product->description }}</p>
    </div>

    <div class="qty">
        {{ Form::text( 'qty', 0, [ 'type' => 'tel' ]) }}
    </div>
@endforeach

{{ Form::select('delivery_day', ['M' => 'Monday', 'W' => 'Wednesday'],
    null, ['placeholder' => 'Delivery Day'])
}}
{{ Form::submit('Place Order') }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

When I submit the request only the fields to the `Order` table are saved,

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    // Validate
    $request->validate([
        'qty'=> 'integer',
      ]);

  # Create New Order
    $order = new Order;
    $id = Auth::user()->id;
    $order->user_id = $id;

     // passed in parameters of form (not qty)

    auth()->user()->orders()->save($order); // save order

  # Pivot attach()

    HERE I AM LOST

    return redirect('complete')->with('success', 'Order has been created');
}
```

I believe it is the fact that I am trying to pass multiple products in one form, (which I believe i should be able to just pass as an arry while I use `attach()`.

I have tried various solutions and I am still unable to ever get the pivot table to populate.

My last attempt was to pass the `product_id` through a hidden field and then running this.

```php
    $attach_data = [];
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($product_ids); $i++);
    $attach_data[$product_ids[$i]] = ['qty' => $qtys[$i]];

    $order->product_ids()->attach($attach_data);
```

However, this did not work.

Comment: How have you tried to use `attach()`? Can you add the code to your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the docs (https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships) this is one way to attach multiple items:

```
$user->roles()->attach([
  1 => ['expires' => $expires],
  2 => ['expires' => $expires]
]);
```

So you have to modify this:

```
# Create New Order
$order = new Order;
$id = Auth::user()->id;
$order->user_id = $id;
$order->save();

// change this for your array of ids
$products_to_sync_ids = [1,3,23];

$sync_data = [];
$qty = 1; <----- I dont know if you are inserting them with the same qty
for($i = 0; $i < count($products_to_sync_ids); $i++))
   $sync_data[$products_to_sync_ids[$i]] = ['qty' => $qty];

$order->products()->sync($sync_data);
```

Try and check if the products are inserting correctly on the pivot table and then modify the code to insert every code with his quantity.

Comment: I was surprisingly close, hope this helps others.